# Taking NSString and modifying it for another NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSString` that's giving out input values on a control.

I want to take these values and convert them for user display. AKA, **Value 0.7 is 1**, **value 1.3 is 5**. etc.

Ive tried writing an if statement, such as

```
if self.label.text = 0.7
   self.labelone.text = 1
```

But I cant figure out where it should be written or what code I should be using.
I only need 6 values so even though its a messy way to implement it, I dont mind that much.

Ive searched many resources and I cannot find anything or anyone trying to attempt something similar, which leads me to believe its either incredibly simple, or I'm missing out on something incredibly simple.

Here is the code for the `UILabel` I'm trying to convert and modify

```
- (IBAction)rotaryKnobDidChange
{
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", self.rotaryKnob.value];
    self.slider.value = self.rotaryKnob.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two variables you should use `==` instead of `=`. And you're trying to compare `CGFloats` with `NSStrings`.

Use something like this:

```
if([yourLable.text isEqualToString: @"0.7"]){
     [otherLable setText: @"1"];
} else {
    if ([yourLable.text isEqualToString: @"1.3"]){
        [otherLable setText: @"5"];
    }
}
```

Comment: This code just dropped in and worked perfectly. 

I'm going to call this one solved. And thanks for the help everyone :)
I did not realise I was using floats either Tom, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're welcome! Keep on learning. Take small steps, but take them constantly. :)

Comment: BTW: When comparing several values, consider using a 
'switch' statement.

Comment: I'll research that one up, I may have to do that for another part of this project :) thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question:

```
if ([self.label.text isEqualToString:@"0.7"])
    self.labelone.text = @"1";
else if ([self.label.text isEqualToString:@"1.3"])
    self.labelone.text = @"5";
```

But I don't think this is really the code you want.